# Synchronize Global Address List to SFDC Contacts through Salesforce for Outlook?

Tags: integration, data-synchronization

My org uses contacts for all employees. This allows us to select them for some fields on accounts, without giving licenses to each employee.

We do not have any automated process for adding and removing employee contacts. I receive a weekly report with new hires and terminations, and I update the contacts accordingly.

I had thought that perhaps the Salesforce for Outlook plugin could be used to automatically update through the Global Address List. However, when SFO asks which contacts folder should be synchronized, the GAL is not one of the selectable options.

I have tried (in Sandbox) to synchronize the GAL to my personal contacts folder, and then allow for upload to SFDC, but this seems very unwieldy and like it would be difficult to keep in synchronization.

Does anyone have experience using the SFO plugin in this way?

Does anyone have experience maintaining contact records for each of their company employees, and if so, how do you keep them in sync?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a RecordType for all contacts that are employees. That would make your job much simpler. You'll then be able to filter for contacts that are employees based on RecordType, plus you'll have a list view of employee contacts. I can't answer your questions about the outlook plug-in, but I doubt that this is the way to solve your issues.